# ¿Cómo puedo sacar hash con una variable dinámica?

Tags: python, hash, sha256

tengo esta forma de sacar hash de un string

```
str = hashlib.sha256(b'algo')
```

Pero ese 'algo' quiero que sea un string dinámico, por ejemplo

```
letters = string.ascii_lowercase
random = ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(10))
```

Comment: Al margen de lo que preguntas, yo no llamaría random a una variable, pues así se llama el modulo de python. Con tu asignación estás cambiando el significado del simbolo random, y ya no podrás usarlo para acceder a funciones de ese módulo.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema no es como obtener un hash, sino como transformar una cadena en un dato de tipo `byte` que es lo que espera `hashlib.sha256()`. La forma habitual de hacer esto es mediante [`encode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.encode)

```
print(type(random))
<class 'str'>

print(type(random.encode()))
<class 'bytes'>
```

Como todas las cadenas, aunque lo ignoremos, tienen una cierta codificación, este es un dato importante a tener en cuenta, en Python 3, todas las cadenas por defecto son `UTF-8`, pero eventualmente podrías manejar alguna otra codificación, por lo cual es importante especificarlo, por ejemplo:

```
random.encode("Latin1")
```

Teniendo un dato tipo `byte`perfectamente puedes calcular el hash:

```
import hashlib

hashlib.sha256(random.encode())
```

Answer (score 0):

Se te olvida poner el output del error si intentas usar una variable de tipo texto que debería ser:

```
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
```

Tienes que especificarle la codificación de caracteres antes tal que así:

```
letters = string.ascii_lowercase
random = ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(10))

str = hashlib.sha256(random.encode('utf-8'))
```

Te encomiendo MUY ENCARECIDAMENTE que no utilizes nombres de variables o de funciones de modulos ya existentes (como por ejemplo usar `random` como nombre de variable cuando ya existe un modulo llamado `random` tambien.

Comment: Porque estaba mal copiado. He replicado tu código en consola y he copiado la linea equivocada mientras hacia las pruebas. Corregido